# How to know which worker a partition is executed at?

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning, rdd

I just try to find a way to get the locality of a RDD's partition in Spark.

After calling `RDD.repartition()` or `PairRDD.combineByKey()` the returned RDD is partitioned. I'd like to know which worker instances the partitions are at (for examining the partition behaviour)?!

Can someone give a clue?

Comment: You can check your web UI for more detail about your jobs, stages and partitions.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question that I'm sure has not so much interesting answer :)

First of all, applying transformations to your RDD has nothing to do with worker instances as they are separate "entities". Transformations create a **RDD lineage** (= a logical plan) while executors come to stage (no pun intended) only after an action is executed (and DAGScheduler transforms the logical plan into execution plan as a set of stages with tasks).

So, I believe the only way to know what executor a partition is executed at is to use [org.apache.spark.SparkEnv](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkEnv) to access the BlockManager that corresponds to a single executor. That's exactly how Spark knows/tracks executors (by their BlockManagers).

You could write a [org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) that would intercept `onExecutorAdded`, `onBlockManagerAdded` and their `*Removed` counterparts to know how to map executors to BlockManagers (but believe `SparkEnv` is enough).

Comment: That was my first idea, too, but I found nothing that could be of any help. I must admit I was a bit surprised to have found it out.